# Geany terminal icon is missing installed in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: command-line, gtk3, geany

I have geany 1.38 installed on Ubuntu 22.04. The terminal button is missing, even though I installed libvte-2.91.so.0, which seems to be loading. There seems to be something in this snippit

```
er@Hertz:/usr/lib$ geany -v
(geany:1531867): GLib-GIO-DEBUG: 22:00:37.383: _g_io_module_get_default: Found default implementation dconf (DConfSettingsBackend) for ‘gsettings-backend’
(geany:1531867): dconf-DEBUG: 22:00:37.384: watch_fast: "/org/gnome/desktop/interface/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(geany:1531867): dconf-DEBUG: 22:00:37.384: watch_fast: "/org/gnome/desktop/peripherals/mouse/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(geany:1531867): dconf-DEBUG: 22:00:37.384: watch_fast: "/org/gnome/desktop/sound/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(geany:1531867): dconf-DEBUG: 22:00:37.384: watch_fast: "/org/gnome/desktop/privacy/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(geany:1531867): dconf-DEBUG: 22:00:37.384: watch_fast: "/org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(geany:1531867): dconf-DEBUG: 22:00:37.384: watch_fast: "/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/xsettings/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(geany:1531867): dconf-DEBUG: 22:00:37.384: watch_fast: "/org/gnome/desktop/a11y/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(geany:1531867): dconf-DEBUG: 22:00:37.384: watch_fast: "/org/gnome/desktop/a11y/interface/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(geany:1531867): dconf-DEBUG: 22:00:37.384: watch_established: "/org/gnome/desktop/interface/" (establishing: 1)
(geany:1531867): dconf-DEBUG: 22:00:37.384: watch_established: "/org/gnome/desktop/peripherals/mouse/" (establishing: 1)
(geany:1531867): dconf-DEBUG: 22:00:37.384: watch_established: "/org/gnome/desktop/sound/" (establishing: 1)
(geany:1531867): dconf-DEBUG: 22:00:37.384: watch_established: "/org/gnome/desktop/privacy/" (establishing: 1)
(geany:1531867): dconf-DEBUG: 22:00:37.384: watch_established: "/org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/" (establishing: 1)
(geany:1531867): dconf-DEBUG: 22:00:37.384: watch_established: "/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/xsettings/" (establishing: 1)
(geany:1531867): dconf-DEBUG: 22:00:37.384: watch_established: "/org/gnome/desktop/a11y/" (establishing: 1)
(geany:1531867): dconf-DEBUG: 22:00:37.384: watch_established: "/org/gnome/desktop/a11y/interface/" (establishing: 1)
(geany:1531867): GLib-DEBUG: 22:00:37.423: unsetenv() is not thread-safe and should not be used after threads are created
(geany:1531867): GLib-GIO-DEBUG: 22:00:37.428: _g_io_module_get_default: Found default implementation gvfs (GDaemonVfs) for ‘gio-vfs’
Geany-INFO: 22:00:37.461: Geany 1.38, en_US.UTF-8
Geany-INFO: 22:00:37.461: GTK 3.24.33, GLib 2.72.4
Geany-INFO: 22:00:37.461: OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (jammy)
Geany-INFO: 22:00:37.461: System data dir: /usr/share/geany
Geany-INFO: 22:00:37.461: User config dir: /home/installer/.config/geany
Geany-INFO: 22:00:37.606: Loaded GTK+ CSS theme '/usr/share/geany/geany.css'
Geany-INFO: 22:00:37.606: Loaded GTK+ CSS theme '/usr/share/geany/geany-3.20.css'
Geany-INFO: 22:00:37.611: System plugin path: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/geany
Geany-INFO: 22:00:37.618: Added filetype Swift (64).
Geany-INFO: 22:00:37.618: Added filetype Clojure (65).
Geany-INFO: 22:00:37.618: Added filetype Kotlin (66).
Geany-INFO: 22:00:37.618: Added filetype JSON (67).
Geany-INFO: 22:00:37.618: Added filetype CUDA (68).
Geany-INFO: 22:00:37.618: Added filetype Scala (69).
Geany-INFO: 22:00:37.618: Added filetype Graphviz (70).
Geany-INFO: 22:00:37.618: Added filetype Genie (71).
Geany-INFO: 22:00:37.618: Added filetype Cython (72).
Geany-INFO: 22:00:37.618: Added filetype Meson (73).
Geany-INFO: 22:00:37.618: Added filetype TypeScript (74).
Geany-INFO: 22:00:37.618: Added filetype Arduino (75).
Geany-INFO: 22:00:37.618: Added filetype Nim (76).
Geany-INFO: 22:00:37.618: Added filetype Groovy (77).
Geany-INFO: 22:00:37.629: Loaded libvte from libvte-2.91.so.0
(geany:1531867): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 22:00:37.633: gtk_widget_get_scale_factor: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Geany-INFO: 22:00:37.635: Loaded:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/geany/addons.so (Addons)
Geany-INFO: 22:00:37.639: Loaded:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/geany/filebrowser.so (File Browser)
Geany-INFO: 22:00:37.641: Loaded:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/geany/geanyvc.so (GeanyVC)
Geany-INFO: 22:00:37.719: Loaded:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/geany/markdown.so (Markdown)
Geany-INFO: 22:00:37.719: Loaded:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/geany/saveactions.so (Save Actions)
Geany-INFO: 22:00:37.720: Loaded:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/geany/splitwindow.so (Split Window)
Geany-INFO: 22:00:37.720: Loaded:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/geany/updatechecker.so (Updatechecker)
Geany-INFO: 22:00:37.735: /home/installer/radiosetupscripts/setup-office.source.sh : Sh (UTF-8)
(process:1531883): GLib-GIO-DEBUG: 22:00:37.744: Failed to initialize portal (GNetworkMonitorPortal) for gio-network-monitor: Not using portals
(process:1531883): GLib-GIO-DEBUG: 22:00:37.747: _g_io_module_get_default: Found default implementation networkmanager (GNetworkMonitorNM) for ?gio-network-monitor?
Geany-INFO: 22:00:37.751: /home/installer/radiosetupscripts/RadioStationSetup.sh : Sh (UTF-8)
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: I use `geany` in Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. And it works for me. Please explain what you mean by 'terminal icon' and 'terminal button'. When and where should it appear?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please [take the tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour) to learn how Ask Ubuntu works. Read [how to ask](https://askubuntu.com/questions/how-to-ask) to improve the quality of your question. Learn what an [on-topic question](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) is. Then take a look to [the help center](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) to see if some _on-topic questions_ are already asked.